# How do I configure servers for a headless wordpress CMS?

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, headless-cms

I have redeveloped my Wordpress site as a headless Wordpress CMS with a Vue front end.

- The front end is hosted on one Digital Ocean droplet with nginx at `www.mydomain.com`
- The back end is hosted on another DO droplet with apache, currently at `www.mydomain.co.uk`

This set-up is functioning fine. The front end talks to the back end API and all the right content is served at `www.mydomain.com`

My problem is with reconfiguring the backend now this is done.
At the moment the full old site is still visible at `www.mydomain.co.uk`
What I would like is the backend to be accessible for admin/api purposes only from `admin.mydomain.com`. Any requests to `www.mydomain.co.uk` I want to redirect to `www.mydomain.com`.

i.e.

- `admin.mydomain.com/wp-admin/edit.php` serves the wordpress admin pages
- `admin.mydomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2` serves the API
- `www.mydomain.com/<category>/<slug>` serves the front end of the site
- `admin.mydomain.com/<category>/<slug>` returns a 404 (or alternatively, redirects to www)

How do I configure the servers and/or my wordpress installation to achieve this? Is it possible?
`admin.mydomain.com` A record already points to the backend droplet.

Comment: FYI this is off-topic here. Might be better to post on wordpress.stackexchange.com or serverfault

Answer (score -1):

You have to make a reserve proxy in nginx.

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/nginx-proxy.html#strapi-server

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers (they're not valid answers)